# Properly handling exceptions from async functions at the top level

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, async-await

I'm having trouble understanding the correct way to handle exceptions from async functions without triggering Node's `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` (since that seems to suggest that I'm doing something wrong).

Normally, in non-async code, unhandled exceptions bubble all the way to the top and eventually get printed to the console. The code that resulted in the exception is stopped all the way back up the stack.

Say I have the following code:

```js
test1().catch((e) => { throw e; });
console.log('got here top-level'); // This will print

async function test1() {
    let test2Result = await test2();
    console.log('got here test 1'); // This won't print
    return test2Result;
}

async function test2() {
    throw new Error('something failed here');
}
```

I would expect that this would do what I want. At the top-most level, it catches the exception from the async functions and re-throws (but now outside any async code or Promises). It should still have the original stack trace so I can find the problem. Happy days, right? But no, this still results in `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and I don't understand why.

What's the proper way to catch all unhandled exceptions from inside Promises?

Comment: `catch((e) => { throw e; });`  Yes, that will end up with and unhandled exception, as your not handling the error, your re-throwing it..

Comment: @Keith I still want the unhandled exception. If there's an unhandled exception I want to know about it! But I also want to do it properly, and `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` seems to suggest I'm not doing it properly.

Comment: Just do -> `catch(e => console.error(e))`..

Comment: @Keith Huh, I suppose that makes sense. I didn't consider that just printing the text is all the exception does when it gets to the top level. Is this the expected way to handle this situation? If so, feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it. (And FYI, I rolled back your edit as I don't believe my code is a good candidate for a snippet: SO doesn't show errors in their mini console and you have to have your console open _before_ running the snippet to see the error; it's just not useful IMO)

Comment: No, the snippet is way more useful, please leave a snippet when you can., especially a fully working one demonstrating the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding comes from this statement...

> catches the exception from the async functions and re-throws (but now **outside any async code** or Promises)

[Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) is still async code. It returns a Promise, just like `.then()` (in fact, `.catch(onRejected)` is simply an alias for `.then(undefined, onRejected)`).

Fun fact, if the `.catch()` callback doesn't return a rejected promise (eg `Promise.reject()`) or `throw`, it returns a successful / resolved promise.

When you `throw e` within your `.catch()`, the return value is a rejected Promise and since this is unhandled / uncaught, you get the infamous `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

To avoid it, simply handle all possible promise rejections

```js
test1().catch(console.error); // returns a resolved promise

// or

try {
  await test1();
} catch (e) {
  // consider this handled
}
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it! Thank you. I couldn't understand why Node was still complaining when I re-threw the exception in `.catch()`, but I hadn't considered that `.catch()` might also be an async function. This also demonstrates a nice shorthand way of logging/erroring the exception, which is `.catch(console.error)`. It makes perfect sense but I wouldn't have thought of that on my own. So `.catch()` returns a promise not because it actually needs to do any async work but just because it allows chaining the `.finally()`, right?

Comment: @Clonkex it supports any promise chain. Eg `Promise.reject("cursed").catch(() => "free frogurt").then(() => throw new Error("frogurt is also cursed")).catch(() => ({ toppings: [] }))`

Comment: @Clonkex you can also return another promise from your `.catch()` callback to help resolve the rejection. A good example of this is an HTTP response interceptor that watches for 401 status, performs a token refresh and replays the original request.

Comment: That's super interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do something like this:

```
async function main() {
  // do some async stuff here
  await someAsyncWork();
}

let cc;

main()
.then( () => {
  console.log('success!');
  cc = 0 ;
}
.catch( e => {
  console.error(e.stack);
  cc = 1;
})
.finally( () => process.exit(cc) );
```

Comment: I like that, but why bother with the `.finally()` and the `cc` variable? If you have both `.then()` and `.catch()`, surely you've covered all your bases anyway? Is it just because `.finally()` is the semantically-correct way to do that? I'm just thinking that it were me, I would have just put `process.exit(0)` in the `.then()` handler and `process.exit(1)` in the `.catch()` handler.